# How do I configure multiple django applications to use the same database?

Tags: python, django, docker, microservices

As I configure my Django applications to use containers I'm left with a problem as I try to separate my processes into smaller images. How can I break logic into smaller components that run in their own containers, yet access the same database?

I realize that in a "true" microservices environment I'd want a different database for each service. However, consider a situation where I have a bit of logic that reads data from a database, and produces a CSV file.

I'd like to break out that into a separate type of image, that contains only that logic and gets a special disk mount to write the file to. The rest of the applications remain stateless.

So I'm left with needed two django applications, one that reads and writes data to its database, and another one that I can use to spin up and run reports against that same database.

**Option 1:** Is that I keep using the same application, where the models have already been defined. I spin up one container for processing, and spin up another container of the same image for use for reporting. While this would work, it seems like it would be a better pattern to isolate the behavior to a specific application.

**Option 2:** ... What is my option two?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use docker network in your enviroment ?

**Suggestion 1:** (simple, but fix your situation) duplicate the models.py in two applications. Connect in database using the container database name.
If you need to call a function (def) between containers you can use API's call, using [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) (Django Rest Framework) ou pure Django with JsonResponse.
Do not forget to create tokens to access this "Api's Calls"

Best Regards

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had briefly considered this, but i was concerned about maintaining the file in both locations. Plus, I think special attention would need to be taken to be sure that both applications don't generate a migration for the same models.py.